# Openlayers infobox?

Tags: openlayers-2

is there any infobox available in Openlayers same like google maps infobox 
[google maps infobox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html)

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers has some different popups, but the most similar to google maps, as CaptDragon suggest, is the OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud.

Comment: yes `OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud` is the best one. all the rest are kind of lame. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [popupMatrix example](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/popupMatrix.html).

Here's another [example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/sundials.html).

Comment: Links are not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

Agree with CaptDragon's comment above as I thought the same thing.  So I started to look into other options and found GeoExt (www.geoext.org).  Here's a link to an example of their popup solution:

http://api.geoext.org/1.1/examples/popup.html

The nice thing about using this style is that you can use many of the ExtJS capabilities in the popup as well.  So, we currently have popups with tabs which allow the user to select different bits of info when one clicks on a point.

We're using GeoExt 1.0 and ExtJS 3.4 presently.  GeoExt 1.1 recently came out but there might be an issue with the Tree code and seems like some of the examples are now broken.  Still, I used the popup without incorporating GeoExt further.  But, you can also download 1.0 still.

There are other options out there to look into as well.  But, GeoExt works fairly well with OpenLayers and one of the reasons I decided to use it for our app.